# Why are laravel delete and show methods not working in laravel 5?

Tags: php, post, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am pretty sufficient in restful resources and how they work and having built rails apps with restful I understand the premise of it all and how they work, however laravel is really not working whatever I do.

I have a set of posts with resources for each method such as:

```
GET|HEAD | posts | posts.index | Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index                 
GET|HEAD | posts/create | posts.create  | Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create |
POST| posts| posts.store   | Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store |            
GET|HEAD | posts/{posts} | posts.show    | Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\PostsController@show |            
GET|HEAD | posts/{posts}/edit | posts.edit    | Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\PostsController@edit                  
PUT | posts/{posts}| posts.update  | Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\PostsController@update                
PATCH | posts/{posts} |                                      Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\PostsController@update                
DELETE | posts/{posts} | posts.destroy
```

As you can see this is pretty simple right? Well I am having trouble basically showing any data on a post/url-title-page and deleting a post on the /posts index page. When I try to delete it says post deleted in message but its still there and when I view the post show url it shows blank page where the data should be but is not showing up and when I access the url for /edit on that post it shows me nothing in the fields. Basically all is blank.

On the index posts page I can see the below which is correct:

[image]

On the single view I get this:

[image]

There should be a title in the grey bar and an image above that with body text below all that but I see nothing.

I am using the package eloquent sluggable for creating slugs and to access them as above.

Here is my posts controller:

```
<?php namespace Boroughcc\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use Redirect;
use Storage;
use SirTrevorJs;
use STConverter;
use Validator;
use Image;
use Boroughcc\Post;
use Boroughcc\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Request;

class PostsController extends Controller { 
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create(Post $post)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        return view('posts.create', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Post::$rules);

        // Get the uploaded file object
        $img = Input::file('featured_image');

        // Generate the necessary file details
        $extension = pathinfo($img->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . '.' . $extension;
        $path = 'img/posts/';

        // Move the uploaded image to the specified path
        // using the generated specified filename
        $img->move($path, $filename);

        // Save the post to the database
        // using the path and filename use above
        $post = Post::create(array(
            'title' => Input::get('title'),
            'body' => Input::get('body'),
            'featured_image' => $path . $filename
        ));

        return Redirect::route('journal')->with('message', 'Post created');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @param  int  $slug_column
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        //
        $post->find($post);

        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        $post->find($post->slug);
        $this->middleware('auth');
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Post $post)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $input = Request::except('_method','_token','featured_image');

        $destinationPath = 'img/posts/'; 

            if(Request::hasFile('featured_image')) {
                $img = Request::file('featured_image');

                $extension = pathinfo($img->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . '.' . $extension;

                $img->move($destinationPath, $filename);

                $post->update(array(
                    'featured_image' => $destinationPath . $filename
                ));

            } else {
                // ...
            }
            $post->update($input);

        return Redirect::route('posts.show', $post->getSlug() )->with('message', 'Post updated.');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Post::destroy($id);
        return Redirect::route('posts.index')->with('message', 'Post deleted.');

    }

}
```

In my routes file I have the post resources route and then something to bind the slug column as an accessible post singular page like so:

```
/// Posts ////


Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

Route::match(array('PATCH'), "/posts", array(
      'uses' => 'PostsController@update',
      'as' => 'posts.update'
));

Route::bind('post', function($value){
    $Model = Post::where('slug_column', '=', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
```

Then in my Post model I have this setup:

```
<?php namespace Boroughcc;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model implements SluggableInterface {

    use SoftDeletes;

    // protected $fillable = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = array('title', 'featured_image', 'body');

    protected $guarded = ['_method'];

    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = array(
        'build_from' => 'title',
        'save_to'    => 'slug_column',
    );

    public static $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'featured_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp,gif,svg'
    );

}
```

So I can create a post but I cannot view the single post nor delete the post correctly.

Comment: A white screen typically indicates an error message, either in Laravel's logs or your webserver's. If you're using Homestead, check `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` in your VM.

Comment: its not fully white/blank as you can see its still rendering html etc

Answer (score 3):

There are probably at least 2 problems here, but you should look at your logs as @ceejayoz mentioned.

You use here route model binding, so your `show` method should look like this:

```
 public function show(Post $post)
 {
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
 }
```

and not

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    //
    $post->find($post);

    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

because now you are trying to to launch find method on Eloquent model to find Eloquent model. This won't work.

The same is for your `destroy` method.

The code should look like this:

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();
    return Redirect::route('posts.index')->with('message', 'Post deleted.');
}
```

**EDIT**

In addition you should also return something for route model binding this way + you should bind to `posts` and not to `post` (in your routes you have `{posts}`) so the correct way will be:

```
Route::bind('posts', function($value){
    return Post::where('slug_column', '=', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
```

Before you were assigning result to variable and didn't return it.

Comment: That show still does not find the data for that post. I wonder if I should take off the findOrFirst in the bind in the routes?

Comment: This now lets me show the post data and edit the post data: `Route::bind('posts', function($value) {
 return Post::whereSlugColumn($value)->first();
});` but I cannot delete a post with this in my PostsController: `$post->delete();`

Comment: @Mdunbavan Have you chaned also argument from `$id` to `Post $post` in `destroy` method as I showed in my answer?

Comment: Yes I have done that too, its got to be the route binding causing it

Comment: @Mdunbavan Are you sure you hit destroy method at all? Try to add at the beginning of this method: `dd($post);` to make sure what this variable contains and if this method is being run at all

Comment: I get the post data returned: "Post {#233 ▼
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #sluggable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
  #forceDeleting: false
}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71709/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-marcin-nabialek).